# How to draw a route between two locations using MapKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

How can I draw a **route between user's current location to a specific location** using MapKit in Swift?

I searched a lot, but didn't find any helpful Swift-specific links or tutorials.

Comment: Search for MKDirectionsRequest, addOverlay, and rendererForOverlay.  There are Swift examples on SO of each.

Comment: thanks for your help. But really i didn't find any valuable result for Swift. Do you have any result or example can i start from it?

Comment: Use Google to search SO -- the answers are here.  Otherwise, look at the documentation for those classes and methods, write some code, try something.

Comment: checkout this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563854/how-to-draw-a-route-between-two-pointsannotations-in-swift

Comment: I'll just link to a tutorial that shows how to do that in Swift: [Ray Wenderlich: Overlays in MapKit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial) This should cover what you need.

Comment: @Anna i followed as you said..but couldnot succeed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775154/error-400-while-adding-route-on-mkmapview?noredirect=1#comment49605946_30775154

Answer (score 26):

Swift 4

```
class MapController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

// MARK: - showRouteOnMap

func showRouteOnMap(pickupCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: pickupCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)

    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

    let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
        sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }

    let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }

    self.mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true )

    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

    // Calculate the direction
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

    directions.calculate {
        (response, error) -> Void in

        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

            return
        }

        let route = response.routes[0]

        self.mapView.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
    }
}

// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)

    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 147.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0

    return renderer
}
```

[image: the image show the How to draw a route between two locations using MapKit in Swift?]

Comment: Hey , i am using the same code but it will not draw me the path with blue line

Comment: please don't forget to use this function

// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)

    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 147.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0

    return renderer
}

Comment: you must use MKMapViewDelegate and with func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer 

you will find renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 147.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

and make renderer.lineWidth = 5.0 to be visible

Comment: I am getting error in calculate distance error block

Comment: for testing i am calling the function this way :

 let locationSource = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7128, longitude: 74.0060)

                let locationDestination = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.3851, longitude: 2.1734)

                showRouteOnMap(pickupCoordinate: locationSource, destinationCoordinate: locationDestination)


M I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I use like this 

let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pickupLatitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: pickupLongitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destLatitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: destLongitude as! CLLocationDegrees)
        
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
        self.showRouteOnMap(pickupCoordinate: sourceLocation, destinationCoordinate: destinationLocation)
}

Comment: maybe you need to use in DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: @Anita: The location drawing won't work in some countries like India. Please have a look at http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions

Comment: @Anita So I think you can use Google Maps in this part if you work on app on India.

Comment: If someone has followed the steps of @AbdelrahmanMohamed and the route doesn't appear, maybe needs to add mapView.delegate = self. btw, why this answer hasn't been marked as the solution yet?

Comment: thanks, @antonio I don't know how to marked as the solution
by the way you are right of course you should add `mapView.delegate = self` to use the map delegate

Comment: @antonio__ I guess you can ask from the question owner to mark my answer as the solution

Comment: I have 3 pinned locations.  CurrentLocation -> Destination1 -> Dest2 -> Dest3. I want to traverse all these 3 locations after dest1 is arrived. From CurrentLocation to Dest1 is arrived route to Dest1->Dest2. After Dest2 is arrived go from Dest2 to Dest3.

Comment: I believe you can do it but you need to memorize destinations in some value and start using it after that

Comment: This works like a charm for me. But need 1 help, want to add some padding in left and right side of the overlay so that it looks in the middle of the map.

Comment: @PoojaGupta I believe you can reduce the range of zoom

Answer (score 13):

```
class MapController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

func showRouteOnMap() {
    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: annotation1.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: annotation2.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    request.transportType = .Automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { [unowned self] response, error in
        guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

        if (unwrappedResponse.routes.count > 0) {
            self.mapView.addOverlay(unwrappedResponse.routes[0].polyline)
            self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(unwrappedResponse.routes[0].polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
            var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

The return is an array of possible routes, usually we just want to show the first. The annotations are the map annotations.

Comment: Since Swift 2, you cannot return **nil** in **rendererForOverlay**. Return **MKPolylineRenderer()** instead.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 + Extension based on bdelrahman Mohamed's answer

```
extension MKMapView {

  func showRouteOnMap(pickupCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: pickupCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
    
    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    
    let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    
    if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
        sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }
    
    let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    
    if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }
    
    self.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true )
    
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
    
    // Calculate the direction
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    
    directions.calculate {
        (response, error) -> Void in
        
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            
            return
        }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.addOverlay((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
     mapView.delegate = self
    
    let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 22.4649, longitude: 69.0702)
    let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0225, longitude: 72.5714)
    
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    
    let sourceRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: sourceLocation, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(sourceRegion, animated: true)
    
    let destinationRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: destinationLocation, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(destinationRegion, animated: true)
    
    let sourcePin = MKPointAnnotation()
    sourcePin.coordinate = sourceLocation
    mapView.addAnnotation(sourcePin)
    
    let destinationPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    destinationPin.coordinate = destinationLocation
    mapView.addAnnotation(destinationPin)
    

    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
    
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate { (response, error) in
       guard let response = response else {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
            return
        }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
        
        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
     let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.lineWidth = 4.0
    return renderer
}
```