# shows user location and direction in ios using mkmapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am new to mapview,i want to show current location of user and get direction into map in which i want to fix destination but source is not fix.
I get the current location using CLLocation class.
Now i want to fix destination and make it disable and not editable.

please give me some hints how to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: You just want to show 2 location in mapview and did you want to show route of particular 2 address ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes

Comment: check this link it may help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319643/how-to-draw-a-route-between-two-locations-using-mapkit-in-swift]

Comment: if you want to show path from one pin to another pin so you have to use PloyLine method. It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**First make your view controller implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol and declare the properties you will need:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView; //this is your map view
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine; //your line
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView;
```

**then in viewDidLoad (for example, or wherever you initialize)**

//initialize your map view and add it to your view hierarchy - **set its delegate to self***

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, lon1); 
coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat2, lon2);


self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible

[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

**then implement the MKMapViewDelegate's method -(MKOverlayView *)mapView:viewForOverlay:**

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine] autorelease];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

        }

        return self.routeLineView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```